# Is there a way to set the data type of the protocol in function pointer?

Tags: swift, types, protocols

Is there a way to set the data type of the protocol in function pointer in swift?

Here's my protocol `ICRUDOperation`

```swift
public protocol ICRUDOperation {
    associatedtype T
    func insert(data:T)
    func update(data:T)
    func get(data:T) -> [T]
    func getList(data: BaseModel) -> [T]
    func getPage(data: BaseModel) -> [T]
    func delete(data: T)
}
```

Which I try to use in:

```swift
func delegate1<W>(sqlite: W, service: W, data: W.T) where W: ICRUDOperation {
    sqlite.insert(data: data)
}
var decision = [String : [String:((ICRUDOperation, ICRUDOperation, T) ->())?]]()

func fillDecision() {
    decision["Person"]?["1"] = Delegate1
}
```

I get this error in decision

```
Protocol 'ICRUDOperation' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

Error for `fillDecision()`:

```
Cannot assign value of type '(_, _, _.T) -> ()' to type '((ICRUDOperation, ICRUDOperation, _) -> ())??'
```

Comment: I changed your leading uppercase letters in function names and most variable names to be lowercase, which is Swift standard, to help with readability

Answer (score 1):

Once you've added an associated type, there is no longer any such thing as a "ICRUDOperation". A PAT (protocol with associated type) has no existential form; it exists in order to attach methods to *other* types, or to restrict what concrete types may be passed to a generic function. You cannot store a PAT in a variable or dictionary or anywhere else. A protocol (and doubly-so a PAT) is not an abstract class.

The most critical thing to understand is that associated types are selected by the *implementation*, not by the caller. So in your example, `T` would be selected by the implementation of ICRUDOperation (in the same way that Array chooses its Collection.Index to be Int; you don't get to pick that). Generics allow the *caller* to select the type, which looks more like what you're trying to achieve.

How you resolve this depends on your use case, which is difficult to understand from your example. What is the goal of `decision`?

It would be helpful if you would demonstrate what you expect two or three different implementations of ICRUDOperation would look like. I'm not sure what you intend "an implementation of an operation" to mean.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand how you want to use this so this my idea of how to use the protocol. I am not sure if this answers your question but maybe it can help getting you closer to a solution.
Say we have this model we want to persist

```
struct Item {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}
```

Then we need a handler that can perform the db operations

```
struct ItemDbHandler: ICRUDOperation {
    typealias T = Item

    func insert(data: Item) {
        print("\(#function) \(item)")
    }

    func update(data: Item) {
        print("\(#function) \(item)")
    }

    func get(data: Item) -> [Item] { //shouldn't this return 1 element
        print("\(#function) \(item)")
        return []
    }
    // and so on...
}
```

And with some delegate function

```
func delegateUpdate<W>(sqlite: W, service: W, data: W.T) where W: ICRUDOperation {
    sqlite.update(data: data)
}
```

we can either work with the handler directly or via the function

```
var item = Item(id: 1, name: "ABC")
var handler = ItemDbHandler()
handler.insert(data: item)
item.name = "abc"

delegateUpdate(sqlite: handler, service: handler, data: item)
```

Running this in a playground yields

> insert(data:) Item(id: 1, name: "ABC")
>   update(data:) Item(id: 1, name: "abc")

I don't understand what you want to do `fillDecision` so I skipped it for now.