# I get an error when setting the dictionary in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I get an error when I set the dictionary in swift.

I use a dictionary like a hashmap

```
public class Decision : CRUDOperation<Any> {
var funct = [String : (CRUDOperation<Any>,CRUDOperation<Any>,Any)->()]()
var obj =  [String : [String : (CRUDOperation<Any>,CRUDOperation<Any>,Any)->()]] ()
static var Decision1 = [String : [String:(CRUDOperation<Any>,CRUDOperation<Any>,Any)->()]]()
func FillDecision() {
        print("Fill Decision")
        funct["1"] = Delegate1
        Decision.Decision1["Person"] = funct
}

func Delegate1(sqlite: CRUDOperation<Any>, service: CRUDOperation<Any>, data: Any) {
    print("Delegate1")
    sqlite.insert(data: data)

}
```

I get an error in below class

```
    public class PersonManager : CRUDOperation<Person> {
var personSqlite = PersonSqlite()
var personService = PersonService()
public override func insert(data: Person) {
    print("insert in E")
    data.objectState = Enums.ObjectState.New
    Decision.Decision1["Person"]!["1"]((personSqlite,personService,data))
}}
```

when I want set this:

```
Decision.Decision1["Person"]!["1"]((personSqlite,personService,data))
```

Error : Cannot call value of non-function type '((CRUDOperation, CRUDOperation, Any) -> ())?'

Comment: Maybe it would help if you gave some feedback on the answers in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599233/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-data-type-of-the-protocol-in-function-pointer) first since that question is strongly related to this one,

Comment: Yes please try to avoid creating duplicate questions :)